# Mouse_Event MOUSEVENTF_ for scroll wheel click

Tags: windows, lazarus, freepascal

Is there a `MOUSEEVENTF_` that can be used with `Mouse_Event()` to send a scroll wheel click?

It seems that the scroll wheel click is not equivalent to a middle-click (stupid moment thinking that, apparently), but the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx) only seem to talk about scrolling/rotating the wheel and tilting it.

(I have also noticed that `Mouse_Event` has been superceded, but I haven't looked into whether `SendInput` works in fpc/lazarus yet and that is what I am working in)

Comment: The system does not define a wheel button to be pressed.

Comment: I don't think it's stupid, I think it's the MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN. It's been a long time I haven't seen a 3 *fore* button mouse.

Comment: The reason there is no wheel button press is that wheel buttons scroll. If your wheel button doubles as a middle button then send middle button events. If your wheel button is not a middle button then you need to work out what it is.